# SQL Server display first, second, and third values with same value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a query in SQL Server but having some difficulties. I will try to supply some sample data so it is easier. There are multiple tables I am trying to pull from:

Units:

```
UnitID
------
 101
 102
 103
 104
 etc..
```

Jobs:

```
JobID 
------
 1    
 2  
etc.
```

Job Units:

```
UnitID | JobID | DispatchDate
-----------------------------
 102   |  12   |  Dec 12 2015
 104   |  14   |  Dec 12 2015
 102   |  18   |  Dec 12 2015
 108   |  18   |  Dec 12 2015
 102   |  11   |  Dec 12 2015
 104   |  10   |  Dec 12 2015
```

What I would like for a desired outcome would reflect this data set:

```
UnitID | Job 1 | Job 2 | Job 3 
------------------------------
  102  |  12   |  18   |  11
  103  |       |       |
  104  |  14   |  10   |
  105  |       |       |
  106  |       |       |
  107  |       |       |
  108  |  18   |       |
```

So basically, I want to display the job the Unit has been out to up to three jobs, but I still need to show the other units that haven't gone out, or only have gone out once or twice.

I currently am exporting this data set out to three separate listviews and using three separate stored procedures, but this isn't getting the job done and is a mess, so I won't even bother posting my code, but if needed I can.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: As per request of /u/Pasty, here is the code I am working on:

```
select UnitID, case when (select COUNT(JobID)
                                                                from JobUnits
                                                                where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                                and DispatchDate='Dec 12 2015') >= 1
                                                        then (select top 1 JobID
                                                                from JobUnits
                                                                where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                                and DispatchDate='Dec 12 2015'
                                                                order by JobID asc )
                                                        else null 
                                                        end as 'Job 1', case when (select COUNT(JobID)
                                                                from JobUnits
                                                                where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                                and DispatchDate='Dec 12 2015') >= 2
                                                        then (select top 1 JobID
                                                                from JobUnits
                                                                where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                                and DispatchDate='Dec 12 2015'
                                                                order by JobID desc )
                                                        else null
                                                        end as 'Job 2', case when (select COUNT(JobID)
                                                                from JobUnits
                                                                where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                                and DispatchDate='Dec 12 2015') >= 3
                                                        then (select top 1 JobID
                                                                from JobUnits
                                                                where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                                and DispatchDate='Dec 12 2015'
                                                                order by JobID asc )
                                                        else null
                                                        end as 'Job 3'
from Units U
order by UnitID asc
```

Comment: You don't have anything in the tables you posted that relates a Unit or Job to a customer. As posted there isn't much of a way to provide an answer. You need to provide table structures and some sample data. sqlfiddle.com would be a good place to start.

Comment: @SeanLange I updated the question with my Jobs table, and removed the Customers sections of the query, as I believe it may just be extra info that is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this scenario with quite a mess of code, but it works and I'm tired, so I am just going to go with it.

```
select UnitID, case when (select COUNT(JobID)
                                                                from JobUnits
                                                                where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                                and DispatchDate='Dec 4 2015') >= 1
                                                        then (select top 1 JobID
                                                                from JobUnits
                                                                where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                                and DispatchDate='Dec 4 2015'
                                                                order by JobID asc )
                                                        else null 
                                                        end as 'Job 1', case when (select COUNT(JobID)
                                                                                    from JobUnits
                                                                                    where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                                                    and DispatchDate='Dec 4 2015') >= 1
                                                                        then (select Customer
                                                                                from Customers C
                                                                                full
                                                                                where CustomerID=())
                                                                        else null 
                                                                        end as 'Customer 1', 
                                                        case when (select COUNT(JobID)
                                                                from JobUnits
                                                                where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                                and DispatchDate='Dec 4 2015') >= 2
                                                        then 
                                                        (SELECT TOP 1 JobID 
                                                        FROM 
                                                        ( 
                                                            SELECT TOP 2 JobID 
                                                            from JobUnits
                                                            where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                            and DispatchDate='Dec 4 2015'
                                                            ORDER BY JobID desc
                                                        ) sub 
                                                        ORDER BY JobID asc) 
                                                        else null
                                                        end as 'Job 2', 
                                                        case when (select COUNT(JobID)
                                                                from JobUnits
                                                                where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                                and DispatchDate='Dec 4 2015') >= 3
                                                        then 
                                                        (SELECT TOP 1 JobID 
                                                        FROM 
                                                        ( 
                                                            SELECT TOP 3 JobID 
                                                            from JobUnits
                                                            where UnitID=U.UnitID
                                                            and DispatchDate='Dec 4 2015'
                                                            ORDER BY JobID desc
                                                        ) sub 
                                                        ORDER BY JobID desc) 
                                                        else null
                                                        end as 'Job 3'
from Units U
order by UnitID asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use LEFT JOIN in order to achieve the desired result. If you have table **A** and **B** and want to display *matches in B* and all items from A,  **LEFT JOIN** allow's you to do that. A good visual explanation of [SQL JOINS can be found here - A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

How can you create the desired output in your case (I am assuming the tables are named Job, Unit ans Unit_has_Job):

```
Unit | UnitId
-----------
        101
        102
        103
        104
        105
        107

Job | JobId
--------------
        1
        2
        3
        4
        5

Unit_has_JobId | UnitId | JobId
----------------------------------
                101  | 1
                101  | 3
                101  | 4
                102  | 4
                105  | 3

select u.UnitId, ISNULL(j.JobId, 0) as [JobId]  from unit as u
left join unit_has_job as uhj on u.UnitId = uhj.UnitId
left join job as j on uhj.JobId = j.JobId
```

The result is:

```
UnitId | JobId
101 | 1
101 | 3
101 | 4
102 | 4
103 | 0
104 | 0
105 | 3
107 | 0
```

I have created an example in [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7f6b).

With the [ISNULL function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) you mark the *empty* slots. The different `JobId` for every `UnitId` is equivalent to the columns in your desired output.

Using [LINQ2SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [GroupBy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx) you can easily group the jobs per unit from the result and iterate over them:

```
var jobsPerUnit = result.GroupBy (r => r.UnitId);
foreach (var jobs in jobsPerUnit)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unit: " + jobs.Key);
    foreach (var job in jobs)
    {
        if (job.JobId > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Job: " + job.JobId);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("=================");
}
```

The output:

```
Unit: 101
Job: 1
Job: 3
Job: 4
=================
Unit: 102
Job: 4
=================
Unit: 103
=================
Unit: 104
=================
Unit: 105
Job: 3
=================
Unit: 107
=================
```

Columns in SQL are the result of a selection/projection, which can't be created so easily dynamically. One possible solution is to use [dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) in order to create a temp table, fill it and then select from this temp table, but the overhead is probably not worth it.  You still need a cursor for this solution.

If you want to do everything on the SQL-side, then one possible solution would be to iterate with a cursor over the result and group by `UnitId`.

Comment: Using the code you supplied doesn't create the output wanted. When a Unit has more than one job, it created a record below it. I need it in a separate column.

Comment: I am extending my answer currently. You can't do this in SQL so easily (AFIK event at all, or at least not so easy). You need either handle the output in the code or iterate with a cursor over the result, grouped by UnitId.

Comment: Hmm I am realizing this isn't too easy. I am currently working on some code that is somewhat working. I can post it on my question.

Comment: Share your code. With LINQ2SQL the processing of the output, generated by the example SQL-query in my answer, is trivial.

Comment: I did an absolute hack-job of case statements, but I think I am getting it to work somewhat. My question is updated.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to get to the same result, where you don't need to run inner selects all the time. This yields a much simpler execution plan and faster execution if you put on the proper indexes.

Note that there is a LEFT JOIN in the inner query  (`LEFT JOIN JobUnits ju`), that will produce an row for each row in `Units`, regardless if it has related JobUnit.

```
select UnitID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN cnt=1 THEN JobID ELSE 0 END) AS Job1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cnt=2 THEN JobID ELSE 0 END) AS Job2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cnt=3 THEN JobID ELSE 0 END) AS Job3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cnt=4 THEN JobID ELSE 0 END) AS Job4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cnt=5 THEN JobID ELSE 0 END) AS Job5
FROM (
    select ju.UnitID, ju.JobID, count(1) as cnt
    FROM Units u
    LEFT JOIN JobUnits ju on (u.UnitID = ju.UnitID)
    LEFT JOIN JobUnits ju2 on (ju.UnitID = ju2.UnitID AND ju.UnitID <= ju2.UnitID)
)
GROUP BY UnitID
```

The only disadvantage of this SELECT that it will not preserve the order (12, 18, 11 in case of 102), instead it orders it ascending way (11, 12, 18) - I don't know if it is an advantage or disadvantage in your business case.

You can preserve the order if you compare the `ROWNUM`s, but that requires two more subselects, and I'm not sure if it worth or not.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I am using SQL Server 2012, and this throws quite a few errors. I actually ended up using my mess of code that works for me. I posted it in the answers

Answer (score 1):

I was just playing around and this is what I came up with:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/863d9/2)

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.UNITS', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.UNITS
GO

CREATE TABLE UNITS(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), UnitID INT, JobID INT, DispatchDate DATETIME)
GO

INSERT INTO UNITS 
    VALUES(102, 12, 'Dec 12 2015')
           ,(104, 14, 'Dec 12 2015')
           ,(102, 18, 'Dec 12 2015')
           ,(108, 18, 'Dec 12 2015')
           ,(102, 11, 'Dec 12 2015')
           ,(104, 10, 'Dec 12 2015')
           ,(103, NULL, NULL)
           ,(105, NULL, NULL)
           ,(106, NULL, NULL)
           ,(107, NULL, NULL)
GO

SELECT
    UnitId
    ,Job_1 = JobIDs.value('/JobID[1]','INT')
    ,Job_2 = JobIDs.value('/JobID[2]','INT')
    ,Job_3 = JobIDs.value('/JobID[3]','INT')
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          UnitID
          ,JobIDs = CONVERT(XML,'<JobID>' 
                          + REPLACE(Units.JobIDs, '|', '</JobID><JobID>') 
                          + '</JobID>')
       FROM
          (
             SELECT DISTINCT
                U.UnitId
                ,JobIDs = STUFF((
                          SELECT
                             '|' + CAST(UU.JobID AS NVARCHAR(25))
                          FROM
                             UNITS UU
                          WHERE
                             UU.UnitID = U.UnitID
                          ORDER BY
                             UU.ID, UU.JobID
                    FOR XML PATH (''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
             FROM
                UNITS U
             GROUP BY
                U.UnitID) Units) UJ
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I ended up solving the issue with my code I posted as an answer below